# Basic PHP, guidance needed for Woocommerce customer email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know this is basic PHP, but I am just starting off. I'm editing the Woocommerce email template for customer confirmation emails /woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php

I need to add a link which pulls the customer email and products ordered into the URL. This is where I am up to:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<a href="https://www.example.com?user_email=<?php echo $order->get_billing_email();?>&product_codes=<?php echo $order->get_items();?>">Click here</a>
</div>
```

This is not working for me, but I appreciate my basic PHP knowledge is poor so I've probably made a pretty fundamental mistake here. How can I reference customers email and products ordered into a URL string? Thanks.

Comment: you want to show the order details with purchase product am I right

Comment: @Jinesh well yes, I want to show the customer email in the URL string and also the products ordered.

Comment: I think it' not good pass in the URL string

Comment: @Jinesh OK thanks but I don't know what that means. Do you have an alternative method you can suggest? Thanks

Comment: Create a template file and pass order id into that template and display the product according to the order id.And one thing order id pass through encode method for security pupose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is a wrong practice to update the email templates located at  /woocommerce/emails/ directory directly.

If you need to make customization for woocommerce email templates, you need to copy, the file
from /woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php to 
content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php .

Refer https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ for details.

For the rest, I as stated by @Jignesh , just pass order id , in the url and then in the template, you may get order details using

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

Comment: Thanks Sandhya. Am I getting close with this?

    <?php
    $order = get_billing_email( $order_email );
    $order = get_items( $order_items );
    ?>
    <a href="https://www.example.com?user_email=<?php echo $order_email();? >&product_codes=<?php echo $order_items();?>">Click here</a>

Comment: You are again trying to pass email and product codes via url. This kind of practice causes security breaches. Please keep  the data passed via url to the minimum possible level and hence we recommend just pass order id  i.e.<a href="https://www.example.com?order_id=<?php echo $order->get_id();?>">Click here</a> Then in the template  fetch urder data like this https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: The link is going to a 3rd party website to create an account with the email address contained within the URL.... So I think it's necessary.  I've tried this and I'm getting a error `Exception: Call to undefined function get_billing_email()`